# Kruskal worst case time scenario

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I wanna make a graph that force the kruskal algorithm to worst case. 
So, lets say that we dont care for sorting the edges time or other operations, but we care only about how we make the edges so that the algorithm makes the most union operations when taking them.

Maybe something like this. Can you give me an example with more nodes, or the idea for how to make the graph?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you added the c++ tag because you wrote the question from a purely theoretic point of view. If you're trying to implement this in C++, please clarify that in your question. If you're just trying to generate a larger example, consider asking on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Im trying to implement the graph that will force Kruskal's algorithm in c++.

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443006/create-graph-to-force-kruskals-algorithm-to-worst-case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My idea is, take any graph with more nodes and with less no of cycles.For ex, take a graph with 20 nodes and with one cycle of length 3. In this case, The no of edges we can avoid in MST is only of that contribute cycle. If the graph doesn't contain more cycles we would obviously need many union operations, since most of the vertices belong to different sets.

Comment: Nice idea. But better take a graph with no cycles at all as Monkey Supersonic said.. right ?

Comment: yeah. then input itself is a MST. :) .. nothing would be changed even if we apply Kruskal. To ensure kruskal is working in Worst cast scenario, I gave this example. example of tree is also good one.

Comment: A last question Im thinkg about ... Does it matter what kind of tree is it ? I mean the cost of the edges or the scheme of the tree affect the speed ?

Comment: Does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have as many union operations as possible, why don't you consider a tree as input instead of a general graph? Simply because in a tree, (trivially) every edge needs to be added to the result set, so with one having *n* nodes, you will have *n* − 1 unions.

The edge weights won't matter any more.

Comment: What about a binary tree for example ?

Comment: If you think the answer can be improved, leave a comment _before_ downvoting!